# Get key and value from associative array and assign variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables, key, associative-array

Here is my array:

```
Array ( [username] => john [email] => johnbobby123@gmail.com [first_name] => John [last_name] => Bobby)
```

how can i assign each value a key variable? for example,

```
$key = $value
```

so in this case, it would be:

```
$username = 'john';
$email = 'johnbobby123@gmail.com';
etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you need php.extract: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

```
$array = ['username' => 'John', ...];
extract($array);
echo $username; // John

otherwise just echo $array['username'] // John
```